# Contextual Action Menu not visually overtaking the Action Bar position in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an `Activity` with a `Fragment` containing a `ListView` with items, on which the user can click and invoke the Contextual Action Mode.

What I like to happen is as the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB) is stating:

> The contextual action bar is not necessarily associated with the
>   action bar. They operate independently, even though the contextual
>   action bar **visually overtakes the action bar position**.

However, this is the behavior I'm currently experiencing. As of now, the Contextual Action Mode appears **above** the `ActionBar`, as the figure below shows.

[image: current]

What I've tried so far without success:

- Moving the `ActionMode` logic from the `Fragment` to the host `Activity`.
- Setting `<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>` in my theme.
- Call `getActivity().getMenuInflater()` instead of `mode.getMenuInflater()`.

This is my code where I invoke the Contextual Action Menu

```
public class NotesFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    private ActionMode mActionMode;

    @Override
    public void checkBoxChecked(Note which) {
        if (mActionMode == null)
            mActionMode = getActivity().startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
    }

    private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {

        // Called when the action mode is created; startActionMode() was called
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // Inflate a menu resource providing context menu items
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.context, menu);
            return true;
        }

        // Called each time the action mode is shown. 
        // Always called after onCreateActionMode, but
        // may be called multiple times if the mode is invalidated.
        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

            return false; // Return false if nothing is done
        }

        // Called when the user selects a contextual menu item
        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.context_delete:
                    //Do work unrelated to topic
                    mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
                    return true;
                case R.id.context_move:
                    //Do work unrelated to topic
                    mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        // Called when the user exits the action mode
        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            mActionMode = null;
        }
    };

}
```

EDIT:
This is the `Activity`, in which the `Fragment` resides:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements DialogFragmentMoveNote.DialogFragmentMoveNoteListener,
        DialogFragmentRemoveNote.DialogFragmentRemoveNoteListener, DialogFragmentAddNewFolder.DialogFragmentAddNewFolderListener,
        DialogFragmentDeleteFolder.DialogFragmentDeleteFolderListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAddNewFolderPositiveClick(Folder folder) {
        //Tell the fragment to do work
    }

    @Override
    public void onRemoveNotesPositiveClick() {
        //Tell the fragment to do work
    }

    @Override
    public void onMoveNotePositiveClick(String chosenFolder) {
        //Tell the fragment to do work
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeleteFolderPositiveClick() {
        //Tell the fragment to do work
    }

    private void displayNoteDetailsFromWidget(String noteId){
        //Tell the fragment to do work
    }
}
```

Why is the Contextual Action Menu not visually overtaking the `ActionBar`, as the documentation state is should?

Comment: Use `<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>` on your theme

Comment: Sorry @PedroOliveira, no difference.

Comment: Call `getActivity().getMenuInflater()` instead of  `mode.getMenuInflater()`. Let me know if it solves anything

Comment: Still nothing :-( @PedroOliveira

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution to this was to add

```
<item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
```

to my `Theme`, which now looks like

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

I found the solution after looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443403/toolbar-and-contextual-actionbar-with-appcompat-v7)