# DialogWhenLarge adjustResize not working

Tags: android, dialog, android-softkeyboard, tablet, adjustpan

The activity theme is `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DialogWhenLarge`. I can not get the activity to resize when keyboard is up. Configuring `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` or `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);`
 has no effect, all I'm getting is `adjustPan` behaviour. However, I can confirm that `adjustNothing` works. Any ideas how to make an activity with `DialogWhenLarge` theme to resize with keyboard?

Result with `adjustResize`:
[image: Result with adjustResize]

Result with `adjustNothing`:
[image: Result with adjustNothing]

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround, but would still like to hear if anyone had a similar problem.

Workaround:

1. Replaced Activity's theme `DialogWhenLarge` with `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog`. This allows the `adjustResize` to behave as expected with `ActionBarActivity`
2. Added `toolbar.xml` layout as `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`
3. Assigned the toolbar as action bar in my Activity
4. Set activity's height for 10' tablets `layout-sw720dp` to 500dp for better presentation

Configure toolbar as action bar:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout...);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

More on toolbar at [android developer blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.ie/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443403/toolbar-and-contextual-actionbar-with-appcompat-v7)