# Contextual action bar appears with toolbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I'm currently using the substitute for the action bar, the toolbar. However, when I long press some text, I end up with two action bars, my toolbar and the contextual action bar.

Here's the code I used to create the toolbar.

```
Toolbar toolbar = ButterKnife.findById(this, R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

I use Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, you need to add:

```
<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
```

To your activity's theme.

See the following link for more information.

[Toolbar and Contextual ActionBar with AppCompat-v7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443403/toolbar-and-contextual-actionbar-with-appcompat-v7)