# Contextual bar above toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I want the contextual bar to replace the toolbar.
But it looks like that:
[image]

I also tried this solution: [Toolbar and Contextual ActionBar with AppCompat-v7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443403/toolbar-and-contextual-actionbar-with-appcompat-v7)

[image]

Still does not work..
Any idea?

And why is the status bar transparent? It's not, when contextual bar is not shown

Comment: If you are using the Toolbar why not just hide it?

Comment: Because that's not the default way it should work. I followed the instruction linked above, but it does still not work and I don't understand why....

Comment: Try setting the theme to Theme.AppCompat instead of .NoActionBar

Comment: I can't because I use a toolbar

Comment: You sure can :D -->  http://javatechig.com/android/android-lollipop-toolbar-example

Comment: Sadly not, tried that, but still get the `This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor....` error